# Could not create type in Web service (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-hosting

I've putted my Web Service to host (somee.com). My code runs fine on local machine, but when i try to run it on host, i got error and i dont know why. Anyone can give me the way to fix this problem?

> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message:

> Could not create type 'WebService.VehicleAPI'.

Source Error:

> Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="VehicleAPI.asmx.cs"
>   Class="WebService.VehicleAPI" %>

Source File: /WebService/WebService/VehicleAPI.asmx    Line: 1

Answer (score 1):

You might have to do this,

Right click on the web service and select "View Markup" and change the markup to use the correct namespace:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="VehicleAPI.asmx.cs" Class="WebService.VehicleAPI" %>
```